# Datatable populates items not as expected

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a datatable. My problem is, that the template generates a new row for each item, but all should be in one row.

Please see this [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bgbzrr)

Expected output is

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
--------------------------
AAA  | BBB  | CCC  | DDD  |
```

Also tried a `td v-for`, but its still generating too much rows. I think the template is also doing a `v-for` behind the scenes, but treating every single item as a new row and not as a td.

What im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

working with this workaround i guess: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bgbzrr

changes in datatable:

```
:items="rows"
```

changes in model:

```
rows:[{row:1}],
```